# How to connect internal IPv6 to IPv4 network

Tags: cisco, ipv6, srx

For the past few days Im having "fun" checking different NAT configuration options on srx240. Im looking for a way to enable lab PC connection to internet.

Is it possible with this spec, or do I have to set up and connect dns64 to firewall?

[image: Network diagram]

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. https://learningportal.juniper.net/juniper/user_activity_info.aspx?id=8996?

Comment: Yes, this is what NAT64/DNS64 solves.